# error with cleansing data with simpleimputer python

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, dataset, data-cleaning

I want to use a simple imputer in python to fill blank values in my data. but I get an error
the data:

```
48.0;80.0;"1.020";"1";"0";;"normal";"notpresent";"notpresent";121.0;36.0;1.2;;;15.4;44.0;7800.0;5.2;"yes";"yes";"no";"good";"no";"no";"ckd"
7.0;50.0;"1.020";"4";"0";;"normal";"notpresent";"notpresent";;18.0;0.8;;;11.3;38.0;6000.0;;"no";"no";"no";"good";"no";"no";"ckd"
```

and my code is like this

```
for d in X:
        for i in range(len(d)):
            if d[i] == '':
                d[i] = np.nan

    X = np.array(X, dtype=((np.float)))

    imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
    result = imp.fit_transform(X).tolist()
```

and I got an error.

> Could not convert string to float: 'normal'

what should I do?

Comment: Please post the error and  ```SimpleImputer```

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51890/how-to-use-simpleimputer-class-to-replace-missing-values-with-mean-values-using

Comment: I still don't get an answer

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to read in your data correctly. If I read in your data above, copy and pasting to my clickboard:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=";",header=None)

df.iloc[:,:7]

      0     1     2  3  4   5       6
0  48.0  80.0  1.02  1  0 NaN  normal
1   7.0  50.0  1.02  4  0 NaN  normal
```

Then you can only impute on columns that are int or float. Note I see some of your example data has some columns with all NAs,

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp.fit_transform(df.loc[:,df.dtypes!="object"])
```